# Seeking to get detailed Exception Message withMicrosoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException

Tags: sql, vb.net, exception, backup

I do have a code in vb.net to backup database from server as following. However, some error may occurred on some specific environment.

```
   try 

   FileName = sBackupFileName
   bkp.Devices.AddDevice(sBackupFile,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DeviceType.File)
   bkp.Incremental = False
   dtStart = Now

   bkp.SqlBackup(srv)

   Catch ex As Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException
 MessageBox.Show("Inner Exception:" & ex.InnerException.Message.ToString() &    ", Operation:" & ex.Operation )

   end try
```

I try to get the detailed Error from with Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException. However, i could only get those general message as "An Exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or Batch".

Is that any other way to get the detailed exception message when error occurred.

Comment: Thank Saurabh on help to format the code.

Comment: Here is info on handling these exceptions. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162127.aspx. You're only accessing 1 inner exception.